# Why is pylint not satisfied with my working code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for writing python but I am having issues regarding pylint.
I have a basic file structure

```
.env
-src
   __init__.py
   -module1
       __init__.py
       -file1.py
       -file2.py
   -module2
       __init__.py
       -file.py
   main.py
```

If I import `some_method` in `main.py` like so: `from module1.file1 import some_method` the code runs as it was intended but `pylint` is not satisfied and says `Unable to import module1.file1`.
If I import it like so: `from src.module1.file1 import some_module` `pylint` is then satisfied but it breaks my code (this isn't how it's supposed to be imported based on my file structure), returning an error saying "No module named 'src' " which is what I expect.
I tried searching for solutions specific to pylint in vs code but none have worked. I keep getting answers or 'solutions' saying it has to do with the path the pylint is executed on.
I am running a virtualenv in the same folder level as my 'src' folder is with pylint installed in that virtualenv with python3.6. Is this a path issue in the settings or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: What is the working directory for `pylint`? Lacking any `__init__.py` files, you technically don't have any explicit packages. However, I *think* that the imports from `main.py`, because it lives in `src`, treat any directories in the same directory as packages. `pylint` appears to use whatever directory contains `src` as an "implicit" package.

Comment: I have `__init__.py` files in each directory (I failed to include that in my question.)

Comment: Is there one in `src/`? That (combined with the difference in what `python` and `pylint` may be treating as the implicit package) could explain it.

Comment: Yes there is. The problem with the former way of importing as in my question is not that the code won't run, it only makes pylint spit out an error but with the later, my code breaks but satisfies pylint. Don't know if this helps but my virtualenv folder and /src folder are on the same level in my directory tree

Comment: Including an `__init__.py` file in `src` is likely incorrect. More likely the actual issue is that you're trying to run `pylint src`, when what you want is to run `pylint` *from* the `src` directory.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you could use would be to reference the module relatively using `.` before the module:

`from .module1.file1 import some_method`

Comment: Sorry, my pc forced restart and I wasn't finished editing my question. I cleared up my file structure a bit with the the import method I'm using. Hope this clears it a bit